# How do I simplify this equation?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

My essential calculus teacher simplified this:

$$\frac{-14x-\frac{\sqrt{y}}{2\sqrt{x}}}{\frac{\sqrt{x}}{2\sqrt{y}}-1}$$

into this:

$$\frac{-28x\sqrt{xy}-y}{x-2\sqrt{xy}}$$

Can someone explain how he did this?
Please show your work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is not an equation, multiplying numerator and denominator by $$2\sqrt{x}\sqrt{y}$$ we obtain
$$\frac{-28x\sqrt{xy}-y}{x-2\sqrt{x}\sqrt{y}}$$ we can simplify the factor $x$ and $$\sqrt{x}$$ it is
$$\frac{-28x^{3/2}\sqrt{y}-y}{x-2\sqrt{xy}}$$

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response!

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac { -14x-\frac { \sqrt { y }  }{ 2\sqrt { x }  }  }{ \frac { \sqrt { x }  }{ 2\sqrt { y }  } -1 } =\frac { \frac { -28x\sqrt { x } -\sqrt { y }  }{ 2\sqrt { x }  }  }{ \frac { \sqrt { x } -2\sqrt { y }  }{ 2\sqrt { y }  }  } =\frac { -28x\sqrt { yx } -y }{ x-2\sqrt { xy }  } $$

Comment: I think a square root is missing in the numerator

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner,thank you